# How to ignore nodes from imported graphs when validating RDF with SHACL?

Tags: rdf, shacl

This shape

```
selfref:NodeShape
  rdf:type sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:property [
      rdf:type sh:PropertyShape ;
      sh:path sh:property ;
      sh:maxCount 0 ;
      sh:minCount 0 ;
      sh:nodeKind sh:BlankNode ;
    ] ;
  sh:targetSubjectsOf sh:property .
```

is processed by engines complient with the SHACL spec correctly, it indeed validates itself. The problem is that all nodes from imported graphs including the SHACL vocabulary are also processed. How to exclude everything connected via `owl:imports` ?

Comment: The only clue I have is : https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl/#security

Comment: Assuming that your shapes have separate prefixes, one could fugure out something using `sh:or` and `sh:pattern`, but such shape wouldn't be "reflexive".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it depends on the implementation. The [SHACL spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl/#dfn-shapes-graph) says:

> Shapes graphs can be reusable validation modules that can be cross-referenced with the predicate owl:imports. As a pre-validation step, SHACL processors **should** extend the originally provided shapes graph by transitively following and importing all referenced shapes graphs through the owl:imports predicate. The resulting graph forms the input shapes graph for validation and must not be further modified during the validation process.

So compliant SHACL processors should extend the original shapes graph, but they don't need to do so.

Comment: Then I would rephrase the question as: is there a way to specify that the shape does not target nodes from imported graphs? If a SHACL compliant processor includes all triples from `owl:imports`, to be able to exclude them, and if they are excluded by default, to be able to include them?